# Dynamic allocated array is not freed

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-leaks

I'm using the code above to dynamically allocate an array, do some work inside the function, return an element of the array and free the memory outside of the function. But when I try to deallocate the array it doesn't free the memory and I have a memory leak. The debugger pointed to the myArray variable shows me the error CXX0030. Why?

```
struct MYSTRUCT
{
    char *myvariable1;
    int myvariable2;
    char *myvariable2;

    ....
};

void MyClass::MyFunction1()
{
    MYSTRUCT *myArray= NULL;

    MYSTRUCT *myElement = this->MyFunction2(myArray);

    ...

    delete [] myArray;
}

MYSTRUCT* MyClass::MyFunction2(MYSTRUCT *array)
{
    array = (MYSTRUCT*)operator new(bytesLength);

    ...

    return array[X];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allocate the array in `MyFunction2`, but you don't return its address.  The argument to `MyFunction2` is by value, so you pass a copy of `myArray` to it when you call it, but the function itself can never change the value of the caller's local variable.

The simple and obvious answer to your problem is to declare the parameter of `MyFunction2` to be a reference, e.g.:

```
MYSTRUCT* MyClass::MyFunction2(MYSTRUCT*& array)...
```

A much better solution, however, would be to use `std::vector`, and not worry about the deallocations.

Comment: you're a genious :D it works with &. I tried to use std::vector but using the Microsoft function that I need to generate the elements of the array I will get some strange behavior. For example, the first element of the array will be at position 0, the second at position 3, the third at position 7, etc.

Comment: @Stefano It would be interesting to know what this Microsoft function is.  It sounds to me like you have an error in your structure definition: `std::vector<MyStruct> v(n)` results in a data structure exactly the same as `MyStruct* v = new MyStruct[n]` (but the data are initialized, and will automatically be deleted).

Comment: the function is GetAdapterAddresses

Comment: @Stefano I can't find any similar array (or any array) in the arguments to `GetAdaptersAddresses`; if I understand the function documentation correctly, what is actually wanted is some raw memory, in which the function will build a linked list of `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES`.  I'm not sure how to best express this in C++: I'd probably just use a `vector<unsigned char>` and `reinterpret_cast`, but possibly a vector of `union { unsigned char[n], IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES }`.  The important point is that you cannot index into an array of `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES`; you have to follow the links in the list.

Comment: Exactly, this is why I used operator new and not new IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES[X]

Comment: @Stefano yes, but `std::vector<unsigned char> buf( byteCount )` will do basically the same thing, with the difference that it will automatically deallocate the memory, even if there is an exception.  All you might want to do is `void* pBuf = &buf[0];`, so you end up with a `void*` (and can use `static_cast` rather than `reinterpret_cast`).  If you're having trouble getting this to work, please post a question with the actual code, even if it is a bit long.  (In this case, IMHO, it is justified, because the interface to this function is very special.)

Comment: could you please post an example of how should I edit the MyFunction2 prototype and the call to the MS function to get your suggestion about vector working?

Comment: @Stefano: it depends.  I'm not really sure what your function does.  One solution would be to have the callee pass in an empty `std::vector<char>`, by non-const reference; this is to be preferred if you want to return an address within the `vector`.  If you can design the code so as to return by value, then you can simply define the `vector` locally in the function.  IMHO, this is the preferred solution, but without more information concerning the semantics of the function, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 5):

The only time you should use `delete[]` is when you've allocated with `new[]`, but that's not what you're doing. You're using `operator new`, which isn't what you should use for general-purpose array allocation. Use `new[]` instead. Or use a vector.

Furthermore, although you pass `myArray` to `MyFunction2` as `array` and then assign a new value to `array` inside the function, that doesn't change the value of `myArray` in the caller. That variable retains its original null value, so your `delete[]` call does nothing. You can change `array` to be passed by reference instead of by value so changes to it will be reflected in its actual parameter in the caller.

Comment: I would use something more C++ style and operator new seems to do the trick. Also, operator new is the only way I know in native C++ to alloc an array by size and not by elements number

Comment: @Stefano `new MYSTRUCT[bytesLength / sizeof(MYSTRUCT)];`

Comment: You're right that `operator new` is the way to allocate by size instead of element number, but you shouldn't do that. If you want an array of MYSTRUCT, then use `new[]` to allocate an array of MYSTRUCT. Anything else just gives you a block of bytes, and whether that block of bytes is suitable to treat as something else is implementation-defined.

Comment: @Pubby Some people said me that the code you wrote rounds down instead of up. Also, unless bytesLength is a multiple of sizeof(MYSTRUCT), I've got a buffer overflow.

Comment: @RobKennedy Inside MyFunction2 I'm using a function from Microsoft that will do some work with the array and will return me myArray as a list of MYSTRUCT. This is why I cannot alloc the array by number of elements (I don't know how many of them there will be exactly). The first time I call the MS function I will get bytesLength

Comment: Get the number of bytes from the API function. Convert to the number of elements, rounded *up*. (Simple division, as in @Pubby's comment, rounds down.) Use `new[]` to allocate the array with that many elements, and then call the next API function to fill your buffer.

Comment: I fixed the problem passing the array by reference, anyway I would like to know why operator new is a bad thing. If I can improve the code I would do it. The code Pubby posted rounds down, how can instead round up?

Comment: @Stefano Round up: `new MYSTRUCT[(bytesLength - 1) / sizeof(MYSTRUCT) + 1];`

Comment: Types can sometimes require certain *alignment* (i.e., the starting address needs to be a multiple of a certain number larger than 1), and `operator new` isn't guaranteed to provide the alignment required by whatever type you're using, but `new[]` is because `new[]` knows what type it's allocating. If you insist on using `operator new`, then free the memory with `operator delete`, not `delete[]`. Every allocation function has its matching de-allocation function; never mix them.

Comment: @Pubby thank you, I'm using your code now. Thank you for pointing me this improvement

Answer (score 1):

You allocate the array inside of `MyFunction2` and never free it. And in the `MyFunction1` you `delete[]` the null pointer, which is a no-op. I'm not sure I can tell you what you should've done instead, because your intentions aren't clear.

Comment: what I want to do is get an array that is allocated inside MyFunction2. After this, I must be able to do some work on it and return a specific element of that array to MyFunction1. If I free the array inside MyFunction2 I will lose everything and inside Myfunction1 I won't be able to use the element that I returned

Comment: You probably want to pass the pointer to pointer or reference to pointer, like James suggested and use `new[]`.